# Date formatting to month uppercase

Tags: python, python-3.x, strftime

I managed to get date by

```
import datetime
getDate = datetime.date.today()
print(getDate.strftime("%Y-%B-%d"))
```

Output is `2018-June-23`

But I want to format output like this: `2018-JUNE-23` (month is uppercase)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `.upper()`:

```
print(getDate.strftime("%Y-%B-%d").upper())
```

Answer (score 17):

To do this directly in the format string, prepend a [carrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret) on the month (`^`):

```
>>> getDate = datetime.date.today()
>>> print(getDate.strftime("%Y-%^B-%d"))
2018-JUNE-22
```

*Note:* This works if you have the glibc extensions (or equivalent features) available on your platform `strftime`. You can check for that by calling [`man strftime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html). If it's not working on your platform, or you need to guarantee the behaviour cross-platform, then prefer to just make an extra function call here by using `str.upper` as [shown in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50994158/674039).

Answer (score -2):

To add on to the answer by [wim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50994363/9374197), in order to make it cross-platform, an additional wrapper is the most accurate way to do this on all platforms.

An example wrapper for Python 3+ would be using format strings:

```py
import datetime

class dWrapper:
    def __init__(self, date):
        self.date = date

    def __format__(self, spec):
        caps = False
        if '^' in spec:
            caps = True
            spec = spec.replace('^', '')
        out = self.date.strftime(spec)
        if caps:
            out = out.upper()
        return out

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return getattr(self.date, key)

def parse(s, d):
    return s.format(dWrapper(d))

d = datetime.datetime.now()
print(parse("To Upper doesn't work always {0:%d} of {0:%^B}, year {0:%Y}", d))
```

Comment: A small comment from the downvoters on improving this would be appreciated